# Visual Studio 2015 Encapsulate Field

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unicode

In Visual Studio 2013 when I encapsulate a field starting with **`i`** letter. It generates a property with starting letter **`I`**

```
int inside = 0;

public int Inside
{
    get { return inside; }
    set { inside = value; }
}
```

---

But in Visual Studio 2015 if I encapsulate the same field it generates a property starting with **`İ`** letter. Applying some indentation rules and adding a space between get and set modifiers

```
int inside = 0;

public int İnside
{
    get
    {
        return inside;
    }

    set
    {
        inside = value;
    }
}
```

How can I change this behaviour? I am using a Turkish keyboard if it is relevant and system culture is Turkish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You typed the Turkish i by mistake, instead of the English i.</strike>

It seems this is a debug of the refactoring code, which doesn't handle the user's culture in a safe way when converting the first letter to uppercase.

The Turkish `i` is one of the [most common examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I) used to demonstrate the differences between cultures, as `I` is the upper case of `ý. Check for example the [Writing Culture-Safe Managed Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms994325.aspx#cltsafcode_topic4) article in MSDN.

<strike>Make sure you've switched your keyboard to English when you want to type Latin variable names.</strike>

As the OP commented, the outcome isn't affected by the keyboard language but the user's locale. This means that the Roslyn refactoring responsible for encapsulating fields perform a `ToUpper` call using the current CultureInfo instead of the invariant one.

Roslyn refactorings are available as open source so it's easy to find the relevant code. In [AbstractEncapsulateFieldService.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/de252f4feb10428bdf4bcbeebc73a8deb19af3c5/src/Features/Core/Portable/EncapsulateField/AbstractEncapsulateFieldService.cs#L362), the `GeneratePropertyName` method makes a call to `char.ToUpper` without specifying a culture:

```
return char.ToUpper(baseName[0]).ToString() + baseName.Substring(1);
```

It should be easy to change this to :

```
return char.ToUpper(baseName[0],CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString() 
      + baseName.Substring(1);
```

**UPDATE**

I [opened an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/5524) on the Roslyn site.

**UPDATE 2**

Unfortunately, the issue was closed as "By Design". It seems that whoever closed it confused the user's *locale settings* with the language used when writing text

Comment: Thank you for your answer . It does't seem to be issue with keyboard but Regional Settings. If I change Regional Settings from "Control Panel > Region And Language > Format" to English it seems to work as expected. I belive 2015 is using systems regional setting wheras 2013 is not.

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you use a US Keyboard and Turkish format?

Comment: Yes keyboard setting does not change anything

Comment: Sounds like they added a "feature" that any programmer would consider a bug. Refactorings in Roslyn are performed by Roslyn, so the problem most likely was introduced there - performing a case change *without* specifying `InvariantCulture`

Comment: Specifically, [in this line](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/de252f4feb10428bdf4bcbeebc73a8deb19af3c5/src/Features/Core/Portable/EncapsulateField/AbstractEncapsulateFieldService.cs#L362) `char.ToUpper` is called without specifying a culture